# On deleting a question

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions

[My meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10634/) seemed to be deleted.
Where can I find an explanation on deleting a question(on meta or main)?
I would like to know on what conditions a question can be deleted.
I searched help, meta, but I could not find it.

Comment: Which question are you referring to?

Comment: @JonasMeyer "Should a near-duplicate meta question not be posted?" or something like that.

Comment: [This one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10634/). I'll add the link.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks.

Comment: Should you need to locate deleted materials in the future: [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/28422) lists your recent deleted questions, and [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/28422) lists recently deleted answers. (Of course, nobody can use these links but you).

Comment: @user90090 Thanks!

Comment: @Makoto: Users with at least 10,000 points can see all questions and answers that were *recently* deleted *not by the poster* using the review menu, and that includes your case here.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks again.

Comment: [Relevant FAQ entry](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: @MakotoKato "I searched help, meta, but I could not find it."  For future reference, Google often does a better job of turning up relevant links than does the SE search interface.  The relevant thread (linked by quid below) is the second result [here](http://bit.ly/1alnUgi)

Comment: @ScottH. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

"I would like to know on what conditions a question can be deleted."

What happened in this case was that 3 users voted to delete it.  You can read details on the technical ways a post can be deleted in general [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/) (thanks quid for providing the link).

The technical mechanism applies regardless of what reason a user chooses to vote to delete a question.  Perhaps a discussion on guidelines for when to delete questions could be useful, but before starting such I would recommend searching first for other meta posts on the matter (I have not done so).

Comment: A user with 20,000 can also vote to undelete, which personally I would if I had the reputation points for it. I don't see any reason for Makoto Kato's question to have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks.
`[Perhaps a discussion on guidelines for when to delete questions could be useful, but before starting such I would recommend searching first for other meta posts on the matter (I have not done so).
]`
I searched the help and meta, but could not find it.

Comment: I think your description is a bit off. mod-tool-priv users (10k+ here) can vote only 48h after closure but then the score of question is not relevant (except for the number of needed votes 3 up to 10), trusted users (20k+ here) can vote without this delay but then there is a score restriction (<= -3 I think) For details see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/on-deleting-a-question

Comment: @quid: Thank you for the correction.  I've had 20k+ for long enough to have forgotten the difference (and didn't look it up), but I thought I knew from experience that $\leq -1$ suffices for  20k+.  Your link is to this thread.  I made it vague for now, with the intention that later I'll make sure a link to definitive rules is included.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link; copied the url from the wring tab here is the relevant meta.SO faq-question to which I wanted to link it says there -3 for Q and -1 for A, perhaps that explains your experience. edit: Now I forgot the link completely! Here the link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that